# Raycast, conflict with transform.forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm expremienting with random raycast mechanics but i'm stuck with a problem:
when i shoot in the air my ray should be rendered parallel at my camera transform.forward (as in the`Debug.DrawRay`). The problem is that the `LineRenderer` takes a strange direction.

Here's my code:`void Shoot(){
        RaycastHit hit;

```
    if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        GameObject b = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, hit.point, transform.rotation);
        b.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, shootOrigin.transform.position);
        b.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, hit.point);
    }else
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, Color.green, 100);
        GameObject b = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        b.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, shootOrigin.transform.position);
        b.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, cam.transform.forward);
        b.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}`
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Debug.DrawRay` "[Draws a line from start to start + dir in world coordinates.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.html)"

That's fine.

However, the LineRenderer [uses positions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPosition.html).

This would be correct:

```
b.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, cam.transform.position + cam.transform.forward);
```

Comment: Aww i completely forgot about this detail, thank you !